# Consulta sobre boton

Tags: reactjs

Ante todo gracias por el espacio brindado.
Mi consulta es la siguiente:
Estoy armando una landing page en react, y tengo que usar css puro, estoy utilizando css modules.
Estoy haciendo un button para realizar el ingreso a la pagina "home".
Pero el link de la navegacion solo puede ser "accionado" digamos, solo te direcciona al home cuando presionas en el texto en si mismo, si apretas en cualquier otra parte del boton no te direcciona.
**Ya intente pasarle el texto a "display:block"** pero solo logro que se aprete en la misma linea donde esta el texto. Si quiero presionar en otro parte del boton no me funciona.
RESUMEN:
EN LAS LINEAS ROJAS NO ME DIRECCIONA AL "HOME"
EN LAS LINEAS AZULES SI
COMO HAGO PARA QUE EN CUALQUIER PARTE QUE PRESIONE ME REDIRECCIONE?

Adjunto imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimine la etiqueta  button, colóquele un id al link y los estilos de glowonhover los aplica a ese nuevo id. La idea es que el link sea el que genere el padding y no el elemento no clickeable (button).

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! Me sirvio!